# Impossible? Finding a closed loop on a six-sided die that crosses face $n$ exactly $n$ times, without returning to a face from one step before

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, puzzle, dice

I'm new here, so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Here is a puzzle that I came up with, which I believe falls someone in the realm of graph theory or topology (I could be very wrong, please correct me!):

> Given a standard six-sided die (with opposite faces adding to seven), is it possible to draw a single non-crossing closed loop on those faces such that the loop crosses through face $n$ exactly $n$ times?
>
> The answer to this question is yes: I found a solution with code and a friend.

[image]

However, if I add one more restriction ...

> The loop can't return to the face it was at one face before (eg. the loop can't go through face 1 and then face 5 and then immediately back to face 1),

... it becomes very difficult to find a solution. So difficult, in fact,

I started wondering if it is possible at all. However, I can't prove one way or the other whether there is a solution or not.

So:

> Is this version of my problem impossible? Or is there a solution?
>
> Also, if you know, what is this type of problem called? It certainly seems related to graph theory and topology, but I don't know if there are any keywords that describe this problem.

Thanks!

---

**Added by @Blue.** Here's a different view of the sample path. (Circled nodes indicate turn-arounds that the revised rules ask to avoid.)

[image]

Here's the path from @DanielMathias' comment to [@JimFerry's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4756083/409), having just one turn-around:

[image]

Comment: This would be graph theory. Check out the Bridges of Konigsberg problem. Yours is not that precisely, but it laid the foundation for what would become graph theory and is related to your problem. It would be a good starting point since you seem interested in this general area not only for historical purposes but also because it is simple and fairly elegant.

Comment: Graph theory problems can blow up in computational complexity if too many conditions are added. Just look at the four-color theorem for the classic example. I doubt this problem is that complicated, but there isn’t an obvious nice solution to me, especially if the number of sides is changed.

Comment: @cameron I agree it seems graph-theoretic, but I don't know a graph-theoretic way to represent that the loop must not cross itself. Do you?

Comment: @MJD Oh! I missed that entirely despite reading the OP a few times. Good catch. That sounds a bit more like knot theory, but I'm not sure if it's useful for this problem.

Comment: There might be a parity constraint. Also sine $n$ has $2n$ exits, but can get at most $r$ of these from an adjacent side $r$ with your revised rule. Side $1$ has two exits into two different sides forcing a two "odd" sides. Side 6 needs 12 out of 14 possible exits opposite to that. The extra exits from sides $2345$ have to go round the dice (not into 1 or 6). That starts to look very constrained to me. One can choose the two exits not used by 6 and I am sure that would create a computable problem.

Comment: One of the notable things about the 6 face here is that there are only 6 different combinations of enter/exit-ing that face (263, 264, ... 465), and it's not possible to use all of them because 265 and 364 violate planarity. So at least one of the combinations has to be used twice.

Comment: @Beekie: I've taken the liberty of adding an image with a different view of your sample path. I hope you don't mind. ... Nice question, by the way! :)

Comment: You can also represdent your graph as an octahedron, the six faces of the cube being the six vertices of the octahedron.

Comment: @Blue I don’t mind at all; in fact, I really I appreciate it!

Comment: “I'm new here, so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong” — flawless!

Comment: I love the new configuration, @DanielMathias, (which contains a 17-digit palindrome!) and the new picture, @Blue!  I wonder how many such 1-turn-around cycles there are?  Unfortunately, my code can't do this.  It can't even produce a short list of candidates, because the "abcab" pattern was essential for this, and that pattern being forbidden relies on there being no turn-arounds.

Comment: Just in case it might be of any use: the graph of the cube can also be seen as the complete tripartite graph on $2,2,2$ vertices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did some computations with strings such as $126453654623654635645$ that represent a cycle of visits to die faces, without regard to whether the path crosses itself.  The number of such cycles without the doubling-back pattern "aba" is $43399$.  Each cycle may be represented as a string that begins with $1$ and continues with the smaller of its two adjacent faces.

We whittle down these $43399$ cycles with planarity restrictions.

First we filter out cycles that connect both pairs of opposite edges of any face: e.g., $265$ and $364$.  Eliminating strings with these crossing patterns leaves $6565$.

A more powerful pattern to exclude is "abcab".  With this spiral pattern, planarity + no-doubling-back forces "c" to appear again on one end or the other.  The spiral then continues forever and the loop cannot close.  By itself this pattern reduces the $43399$ cycles to $1228$.

One might hope that, together, the two filters eliminate all cases.  Not quite.  There are $11$ surviving cycles: $$
126453654623654635645\\
126453654635642635645\\
126456326453654635645\\
126456326456354635645\\
126456326456354653645\\
126456354623654635645\\
126456354635642635645\\
126456354653624635645\\
126456354653624653645\\
126456354653642635645\\
126456354653645632645
$$
These can be ruled out by inspection.  They all contain the substring $64512645$, so the $645$ is "stacked" on top of itself.  Regardless of which one is "on top," the pattern cannot be continued as required in both directions according to one of the $11$ strings above without violating planarity.

Because computations like this are opaque (and, umm, dicey?), I'd appreciate it if someone could reproduce the numbers of remaining cycles after the various filters.  Even better, of course, would be a direct argument, or at least a set of filters that eliminate all cases instead of leaving a small number of them.

Comment: This is amazing! I had thought of trying to represent the loops as strings (lol) but when I got some permutation with repeats code to work my computer seemed to make no progress. Very curious if you have a beefier computer than me or if your code was simply better. Either way, I really appreciate you finding this!

Comment: +1. ... So, if *zero* doublings-back are impossible, can we (and by "we", I mean "you") find a path with fewer than OP's *four*?

Comment: @Blue ```153645635462645365462```

Comment: @Beekie, getting the initial list of $43399$ cycles took about 17 seconds on a laptop with an i7 chip.  I'll post my Mathematica code for that in the next comment.

Comment: state[1] = {{{1}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}};
state[2] = extendList@state[1];
state[n_] := state[n] = cull@extendList@state[n - 1];
cull[list_] := Select[list, #[[1, -1]] != #[[1, -3]] &];
extendList[list_] := Flatten[extend /@ list, 1];
extend[{str_, cnts_}] :=
  {Append[str, #], ReplacePart[cnts, # -> cnts[[#]] - 1]} & /@ 
   Select[next@Last@str, cnts[[#]] > 0 &];
Do[next[i] = Complement[Range[6], {i, 7 - i}], {i, 6}];
makeCycles[] := 
  Select[state[21][[All, 1]], #[[-1]] != 6 && #[[2]] < #[[-1]] &];
Timing[cycles = makeCycles[];][[1]]
Length[cycles]

Comment: @DanielMathias: Nice! I added a picture of the path to the question.